# MacOS native IKEv2 VPN client instead of AnyConnect?

Tags: vpn, cisco, mac-osx, ipsec, ikev2

Similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/323172/how-to-configure-a-cisco-asa-to-support-the-os-x-vpn-client) question from half a decade ago..

Can the native MacOS IKEv2 VPN client be used in lieu of Cisco AnyConnect client?

example anyconnect profile:

`<AnyConnectProfile>
    <ServerList>
        <HostEntry>
            <HostName>VPN01_HostName</HostName>
            <HostAddress>VPN01.cisco.com</HostAddress>
            <PrimaryProtocol>IPsec
                <StandardAuthenticationOnly>false</StandardAuthenticationOnly>
            </PrimaryProtocol>
        </HostEntry>
    </ServerList>
</AnyConnectProfile>`

and MacOS config that is not working (for me):[image]